# Simplifying the function for the common factors; and showing that it contains a multiplicative factor $i e^{i (6 x + 3 b + t)}$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation, parametric-functions, coefficients

I have the given long function for $\{x>0,b,t\}\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\{m,n\}\in\mathbb{N}$. I have two questions:

> This function contains many common factors in polynomial form (as can be seen in the picture below; it is part of this function). How can I ask Mathematica to simplify the whole function by collecting all the terms with common polynomial factors? for example, simplify and collect all the coefficients with the common factor $(5 + x^2 - x^4 - 5 x^6)$, etc. I use `Simplify` but it does not work; using `FullSimplify`, I do not know how long should I wait.

> I am somehow sure that this function should contain a multiplicative factor
> `I E^(I (6 x + 3 b + t))`; how I can check/show this?

```
func:=-16 E^(I (3 b + 6 m \[Pi] + (2 m \[Pi])/n + t + 6 x))x (-1 + x^2)^2 - 
 8 E^(I (3 b + (2 m (-2 + 3 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 6 x)) x (-1 + x^2)^2 + 
 16 E^(I (3 b + (2 m (-1 + 3 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 6 x)) x (-1 + x^2)^2 + 
 8 E^(I (3 b + (2 m (2 + 3 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 6 x)) x (-1 + x^2)^2 - 
 E^(3 I (b + 2 m \[Pi] + x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 + 
 E^(3 I (b + 2 m \[Pi] + 3 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 - 
 E^(I (2 b + 8 m \[Pi] + (2 m \[Pi])/n + t + 3 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 - 
 E^(I (6 b + (6 m \[Pi])/n + t + 3 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 - 
 E^(I (4 b + (2 m (-1 + 2 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 3 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 - 
 E^(I (4 b + (2 m (3 + 2 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 3 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 - 
 E^(I (2 b + (2 m (-3 + 4 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 3 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 - 
 E^(I ((2 m (-3 + 6 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 3 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 - 
 E^(I (3 b + 6 m \[Pi] + 2 t + 3 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 + 
 3 E^(I (3 (b + 2 m \[Pi]) + 5 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 + 
 3 E^(I (6 b + (6 m \[Pi])/n + t + 5 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 + 
 3 E^(I ((2 m (-3 + 6 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 5 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 + 
 3 E^(I (3 b + 6 m \[Pi] + 2 t + 5 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 - 
 3 E^(I (3 (b + 2 m \[Pi]) + 7 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 - 
 3 E^(I (6 b + (6 m \[Pi])/n + t + 7 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 - 
 3 E^(I ((2 m (-3 + 6 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 7 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 - 
 3 E^(I (3 b + 6 m \[Pi] + 2 t + 7 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 + 
 E^(I (2 b + 8 m \[Pi] + (2 m \[Pi])/n + t + 9 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 + 
 E^(I (6 b + (6 m \[Pi])/n + t + 9 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 + 
 E^(I (4 b + (2 m (-1 + 2 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 9 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 + 
 E^(I (4 b + (2 m (3 + 2 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 9 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 + 
 E^(I (2 b + (2 m (-3 + 4 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 9 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 + 
 E^(I ((2 m (-3 + 6 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 9 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 + 
 E^(I (3 b + 6 m \[Pi] + 2 t + 9 x)) (-1 + x^2)^3 + 
 6 E^(I (3 b + 6 m \[Pi] + t + 2 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2) - 
 2 E^(I (5 b + 2 m \[Pi] + (2 m \[Pi])/n + t + 2 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 +
     x^2) - 4 E^(
  I (3 b + 6 m \[Pi] + (2 m \[Pi])/n + t + 2 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) - 
 2 E^(I (5 b + (2 m (2 + n) \[Pi])/n + t + 2 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) - 2 E^(
  I (5 b + (2 m (3 + n) \[Pi])/n + t + 2 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2) - 
 2 E^(I (3 b + (2 m (-2 + 3 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 2 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) - 4 E^(
  I (3 b + (2 m (-1 + 3 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 2 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) - 2 E^(
  I (3 b + (2 m (2 + 3 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 2 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) - 2 E^(
  I (b + (2 m (-3 + 5 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 2 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) - 2 E^(
  I (b + (2 m (-2 + 5 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 2 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) - 2 E^(
  I (b + (2 m (-1 + 5 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 2 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) + 12 E^(
  I (3 b + 6 m \[Pi] + t + 4 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2) + 
 4 E^(I (5 b + 2 m \[Pi] + (2 m \[Pi])/n + t + 4 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 +
     x^2) + 4 E^(
  I (5 b + (2 m (2 + n) \[Pi])/n + t + 4 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2) + 
 4 E^(I (5 b + (2 m (3 + n) \[Pi])/n + t + 4 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) + 4 E^(
  I (b + (2 m (-3 + 5 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 4 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) + 4 E^(
  I (b + (2 m (-2 + 5 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 4 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) + 4 E^(
  I (b + (2 m (-1 + 5 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 4 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) - 12 E^(
  I (3 b + 6 m \[Pi] + t + 8 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2) - 
 4 E^(I (5 b + 2 m \[Pi] + (2 m \[Pi])/n + t + 8 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 +
     x^2) - 4 E^(
  I (5 b + (2 m (2 + n) \[Pi])/n + t + 8 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2) - 
 4 E^(I (5 b + (2 m (3 + n) \[Pi])/n + t + 8 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) - 4 E^(
  I (b + (2 m (-3 + 5 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 8 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) - 4 E^(
  I (b + (2 m (-2 + 5 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 8 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) - 4 E^(
  I (b + (2 m (-1 + 5 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 8 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) - 6 E^(
  I (3 b + 6 m \[Pi] + t + 10 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + x^2) + 
 2 E^(I (5 b + 2 m \[Pi] + (2 m \[Pi])/n + t + 10 x)) (-1 + 
    x^2)^2 (1 + x^2) + 
 4 E^(I (3 b + 6 m \[Pi] + (2 m \[Pi])/n + t + 10 x)) (-1 + 
    x^2)^2 (1 + x^2) + 
 2 E^(I (5 b + (2 m (2 + n) \[Pi])/n + t + 10 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) + 2 E^(
  I (5 b + (2 m (3 + n) \[Pi])/n + t + 10 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) + 2 E^(
  I (3 b + (2 m (-2 + 3 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 10 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) + 4 E^(
  I (3 b + (2 m (-1 + 3 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 10 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) + 2 E^(
  I (3 b + (2 m (2 + 3 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 10 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) + 2 E^(
  I (b + (2 m (-3 + 5 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 10 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) + 2 E^(
  I (b + (2 m (-2 + 5 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 10 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) + 2 E^(
  I (b + (2 m (-1 + 5 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 10 x)) (-1 + x^2)^2 (1 + 
    x^2) - 4 E^(I (4 b + 4 m \[Pi] + t + x)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 4 E^(I (2 b + 8 m \[Pi] + t + x)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^2 - 
 4 E^(I (4 b + 4 m \[Pi] + (2 m \[Pi])/n + t + x)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + 
    x^2)^2 - 
 4 E^(I (4 b + (4 m (1 + n) \[Pi])/n + t + x)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + 
    x^2)^2 - 
 4 E^(I (2 b + (2 m (-2 + 4 n) \[Pi])/n + t + x)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + 
    x^2)^2 - 
 4 E^(I (2 b + (2 m (-1 + 4 n) \[Pi])/n + t + x)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + 
    x^2)^2 + 
 4 E^(I (4 b + 4 m \[Pi] + (2 m \[Pi])/n + t + 3 x)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + 
    x^2)^2 + 
 4 E^(I (2 b + (2 m (-1 + 4 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 3 x)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + 
    x^2)^2 + 
 8 E^(I (4 b + 4 m \[Pi] + (2 m \[Pi])/n + t + 5 x)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + 
    x^2)^2 + 
 8 E^(I (2 b + (2 m (-1 + 4 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 5 x)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + 
    x^2)^2 - 
 8 E^(I (4 b + 4 m \[Pi] + (2 m \[Pi])/n + t + 7 x)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + 
    x^2)^2 - 
 8 E^(I (2 b + (2 m (-1 + 4 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 7 x)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + 
    x^2)^2 - 
 4 E^(I (4 b + 4 m \[Pi] + (2 m \[Pi])/n + t + 9 x)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + 
    x^2)^2 - 
 4 E^(I (2 b + (2 m (-1 + 4 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 9 x)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + 
    x^2)^2 + 
 4 E^(I (4 b + 4 m \[Pi] + t + 11 x)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 4 E^(I (2 b + 8 m \[Pi] + t + 11 x)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + x^2)^2 + 
 4 E^(I (4 b + 4 m \[Pi] + (2 m \[Pi])/n + t + 11 x)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + 
    x^2)^2 + 
 4 E^(I (4 b + (4 m (1 + n) \[Pi])/n + t + 11 x)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + 
    x^2)^2 + 
 4 E^(I (2 b + (2 m (-2 + 4 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 11 x)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + 
    x^2)^2 + 
 4 E^(I (2 b + (2 m (-1 + 4 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 11 x)) (-1 + x^2) (1 + 
    x^2)^2 - 8 E^(I (3 b + 6 m \[Pi] + t)) (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 8 E^(I (3 b + 6 m \[Pi] + t + 12 x)) (1 + x^2)^3 + 
 8 E^(I (3 b + 6 m \[Pi] + (2 m \[Pi])/n + t + 4 x)) (1 + x)^2 (1 - 
    x + 4 x^2 - x^3 + x^4) + 
 4 E^(I (3 b + (2 m (-2 + 3 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 4 x)) (1 + x)^2 (1 - 
    x + 4 x^2 - x^3 + x^4) - 
 8 E^(I (3 b + (2 m (-1 + 3 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 8 x)) (1 + x)^2 (1 - 
    x + 4 x^2 - x^3 + x^4) - 
 4 E^(I (3 b + (2 m (2 + 3 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 8 x)) (1 + x)^2 (1 - x + 
    4 x^2 - x^3 + x^4) + 
 8 E^(I (3 b + (2 m (-1 + 3 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 4 x)) (-1 + x)^2 (1 + 
    x + 4 x^2 + x^3 + x^4) + 
 4 E^(I (3 b + (2 m (2 + 3 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 4 x)) (-1 + x)^2 (1 + 
    x + 4 x^2 + x^3 + x^4) - 
 8 E^(I (3 b + 6 m \[Pi] + (2 m \[Pi])/n + t + 8 x)) (-1 + x)^2 (1 + 
    x + 4 x^2 + x^3 + x^4) - 
 4 E^(I (3 b + (2 m (-2 + 3 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 8 x)) (-1 + x)^2 (1 + 
    x + 4 x^2 + x^3 + x^4) + 
 E^(I (4 b + 4 m \[Pi] + t + 7 x)) (5 + x^2 - x^4 - 5 x^6) + 
 E^(I (2 b + 8 m \[Pi] + t + 7 x)) (5 + x^2 - x^4 - 5 x^6) + 
 E^(I (4 b + (4 m (1 + n) \[Pi])/n + t + 7 x)) (5 + x^2 - x^4 - 
    5 x^6) + 
 E^(I (2 b + (2 m (-2 + 4 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 7 x)) (5 + x^2 - x^4 - 
    5 x^6) + 
 E^(I (4 b + 4 m \[Pi] + t + 9 x)) (5 + x^2 - x^4 - 5 x^6) + 
 E^(I (2 b + 8 m \[Pi] + t + 9 x)) (5 + x^2 - x^4 - 5 x^6) + 
 E^(I (4 b + (4 m (1 + n) \[Pi])/n + t + 9 x)) (5 + x^2 - x^4 - 
    5 x^6) + 
 E^(I (2 b + (2 m (-2 + 4 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 9 x)) (5 + x^2 - x^4 - 
    5 x^6) + 
 E^(I (2 b + 8 m \[Pi] + (2 m \[Pi])/n + t + 7 x)) (3 + 7 x^2 - 
    7 x^4 - 3 x^6) + 
 E^(I (4 b + (2 m (-1 + 2 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 7 x)) (3 + 7 x^2 - 
    7 x^4 - 3 x^6) + 
 E^(I (4 b + (2 m (3 + 2 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 7 x)) (3 + 7 x^2 - 7 x^4 - 
    3 x^6) + 
 E^(I (2 b + (2 m (-3 + 4 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 7 x)) (3 + 7 x^2 - 
    7 x^4 - 3 x^6) + 
 E^(I (2 b + 8 m \[Pi] + (2 m \[Pi])/n + t + 5 x)) (-3 - 7 x^2 + 
    7 x^4 + 3 x^6) + 
 E^(I (4 b + (2 m (-1 + 2 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 5 x)) (-3 - 7 x^2 + 
    7 x^4 + 3 x^6) + 
 E^(I (4 b + (2 m (3 + 2 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 5 x)) (-3 - 7 x^2 + 
    7 x^4 + 3 x^6) + 
 E^(I (2 b + (2 m (-3 + 4 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 5 x)) (-3 - 7 x^2 + 
    7 x^4 + 3 x^6) + 
 E^(I (4 b + 4 m \[Pi] + t + 3 x)) (-5 - x^2 + x^4 + 5 x^6) + 
 E^(I (2 b + 8 m \[Pi] + t + 3 x)) (-5 - x^2 + x^4 + 5 x^6) + 
 E^(I (4 b + (4 m (1 + n) \[Pi])/n + t + 3 x)) (-5 - x^2 + x^4 + 
    5 x^6) + 
 E^(I (2 b + (2 m (-2 + 4 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 3 x)) (-5 - x^2 + x^4 + 
    5 x^6) + 
 E^(I (4 b + 4 m \[Pi] + t + 5 x)) (-5 - x^2 + x^4 + 5 x^6) + 
 E^(I (2 b + 8 m \[Pi] + t + 5 x)) (-5 - x^2 + x^4 + 5 x^6) + 
 E^(I (4 b + (4 m (1 + n) \[Pi])/n + t + 5 x)) (-5 - x^2 + x^4 + 
    5 x^6) + 
 E^(I (2 b + (2 m (-2 + 4 n) \[Pi])/n + t + 5 x)) (-5 - x^2 + x^4 + 
    5 x^6)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that since every function $f(x) = a \cdot [f(x)/a]$ has any nonzero quantity $a$ as a factor, you have some property in mind for the other factor $f(x)/a$?

Comment: Can we be sure that the terms `k * (5 + x^2 - x^4 - 5 x^6)` haven't been split into `k*5 + k*(x^2 - x^4 - 5 x^6)` etc.? For instance, can we rely on `Simplify[Plus @@ Cases[func, _*(5 + x^2 - x^4 - 5 x^6)], {m, n} \[Element] Integers]`?

Comment: The image attached with the OP appears to be wavy which is an illusion.

Comment: @Syed I did not get your comment. My question is why Mathematica does not collect the terms with common factors, say in the given picture, $c_1(-1+x)^2(1+x+4x^2+x^3+x^4)+c_2(5+x^2-x^4-5x^6)+c_3(3+7x^2-7x^4-3x^6)$ where $c_i$ are the sum of the exponential coefficients in the picture.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I wonder why Mathematica does not collect the terms with common factors, say in the given picture, $c_1(-1+x)^2(1+x+4x^2+x^3+x^4)+c_2(5+x^2-x^4-5x^6)+c_3(3+7x^2-7x^4-3x^6)$ where $c_i$ are the sum of the exponential coefficients in the picture; in this way, the function will be shorter.

Comment: There are internal limits in simplification that try to prevent a combinatorial explosion of cases to try. I suspect it's hitting those limits. For instance the `6 m Pi` term in the exponent remains in `Simplify[E^(I (3 b + 6 m \[Pi] - (4 m \[Pi])/n + t + 6 x)), {m, n} \[Element] Integers]` but it is simplified out if any of the other terms are deleted.

Comment: Since you have recognized the form of transformation that you want, try this and see how close it comes to what you want `func//.{a1_*E^a2_*a3_+a4_*E^a5_*a3_->(a1*E^a2+a4*E^a5)*a3, E^a2_*a3_+E^a5_*a3_->(E^a2+E^a5)*a3}` That looks for pairs of items that seem to match the change that you want and combines them and does that over and over until it cannot find any more to do. It is possible that might be too aggressive in some cases and not "just do what you mean!" in other cases. Someone else might be able to offer an even better more dependable way of doing this. Please test this very carefully